# How to Develop a Hash function for traffic license numbers?

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

*Develop a hash function to generate an index value between 0-4999 inclusive for a given traffic license number. Your hash function should generate as few as possible collisions. Hash function should use the properties of license numbers. Hash method should take the license number as a single String and return an index value.  We assume that the license numbers to be in the following format:   City code is a number between 10 and 99 inclusive.  Three letters are any letter combination from English alphabet with 26 chars.  Two digits number is a number between 10 and 99 inclusive.*

I wrote something about this question but, collisions are a lot (1800 for 5k)

```
    static long printValue(String s) {
    long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        result += Math.pow(27, MAX_LENGTH - i - 1) * (1 + s.charAt(i) - 'A');
    }

    result = result % 5009;


    return (int) result;
}

public int hashF(String str) {

    String a = str.substring(0, 2);
    String b = str.substring(5, 7);
    String middle = str.substring(2, 5);

    int q = (int) printValue(middle);

    String last = a + q + b;

    int index = Integer.parseInt(last);
    index = index % 5009;
    return index;




}
```

[Link for orjinal file of licence numbers.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9jds1DCJ3I4UDhfWXlLRGlwLTg)

These are some examples from file of traffic licence number. Collisions must be 300 (maximum).

65HNM25
93DTV23
94WPX23
31RKK46
15YXX90
31MDV74
45BOG99
65JRM50
77VXR55
39TKY41
80MJU73
63QYE57
38FCO80
45ORI16
17CHN73
70SXR63
87CVM74
27EEE85
32PFJ91
50PBA66
70TVK72
15YLS20
80MPM74
21ZRN20
36VVE84
58IDW24
77VDC89
19BVK93
28SUF63

Comment: "Three digits number is a number between 100 and 999 inclusive." I don't see any three digit numbers in your dataset.

Comment: "index value between 0-4999" - your index is between 0 and 5008!

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: True, index should be 5000 but, with prime number we can get less collision. We can change little bit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not your code, but mathematics. Even a (perfect for you, but not very useful) hash code that produces consecutive hashes that are then mod 5000, ie

```
10AAA10 -> 0
10AAA11 -> 1
... etc
99ZZZ99 -> 600 (90 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 90) % 5000
```

will statistically produce over 1800 collisions and is no better than the simplest implementation, which is to use String's hashCode:

```
 int hash = Math.abs(number.hashCode() % 5000);
```

---

It's a silly exercise, as it has no real world use.

Comment: Since the numbers `00-09` are not allowed at the start or end, the perfect generation of consecutive hashes would be based on `(90 * 26 * 26 * 26 * 90) % 5000`.

Answer (score 1):

Your split of the license plate into 3 parts is fine.  But converting the middle to a number, hashing it, then adding the two outside strings, converting that all to an integer, and then finally executing a modulo on that is ... awkward.

I would start off with converting the prefix (10-99) to an integer, and then subtracting 10 to get the range 0-89.

Then, for each letter, I'd multiply the result by 26, and add the index of the letter (0-25).

Third, I'd multiply the whole result by 90 (the range of the final part), convert the final 2 characters to an integer, subtract 10 to convert the 10-99 range to 0-89, and add to the result from earlier.

Finally, mod the result with 5000 to get to required 0-4999 range.

---

Pseudo code:

```
result = toInt(prefix) - 10

foreach letter in middle:
    result = result * 26  + ( letter - 'A' )

result = result * 90  +  ( toInt(suffix) - 10)

result = result % 5000
```

Comment: Thx. Can you give an example for second step ?

Comment: The pseudo code above should help; just adapt your existing loop from your `printValue` function.